# Laravel: Test is unable to see required text

Tags: php, phpunit, laravel-5.1

My test was working fine but today it's giving weird error:

```
vagrant@todo:~/todo.dev$ vendor/bin/phpunit --filter UserSignupTest::testSuccessfullRegister
PHPUnit 4.8.6 by Sebastian Bergmann and contributors.

FUser added with id 80 and the role FULL assigned to it<br>Task Added with title "Clean room" by the user with id: 80

Time: 1.54 seconds, Memory: 19.50Mb

There was 1 failure:

1) UserSignupTest::testSuccessfullRegister
Failed asserting that '' matches PCRE pattern "/(added|added)/i".

/home/vagrant/todo.dev/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Testing/CrawlerTrait.php:278
```

As you can see the text is right there in the sentence: **User added with id 80 and the role FULL assigned to it
Task Added with title "Clean room" by the user with id: 80**

Test case is:

```
public function testSuccessfullRegister()
    {
        $this->withSession(['title' => 'Clean room','summary'=>'Clean Room','files'=>'no'])
        ->visit('/auth/register')
            ->type('Steve','first_name')
            ->type('Jobs','last_name')
            ->type('steve@apple.com','email')
            ->type('stevegivesjobs','password')
            ->press("Go!!!")
            ->see("added");

    }
```

Comment: Is the page meant to be getting redirected or is it getting a response via ajax?

Comment: @RossWilson No. It's not redirecting. It's a simple form Submit

Comment: In that case can you post the contents of your controller method that handles the request?

Comment: Controller submits a record in db and echo text